# Software for benchmarking a slow site?

Tags: web-applications, benchmarking

I have a homegrown CMS running on multiple ISPs. End users have complained that viewing and administering their sites is slow. We suspect the problem is with different ISPs/server that we use. I am trying to determine a benchmark so I can look for a better/more consistent hosting option. To do so - I need data.

My goal is measuring load times for:

- logged in users
- not logged in users
- performing different tasks
- at different times of the day
- with different user volumes

..and then being able to run the same tests on different servers.

Can anyone recommend software that would help me automate this?

I am on a MacBook running OSX 10.5x, but have access to Windows XP.

Thanks.

Comment: I see a vote to close this, but actually feel it belongs here.  Performance benchmarking is a valuable skill for developers.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you will need several tools to accomplish what you're looking for (particularly automated testing for different times of the day), but you could find the most egregious problems with Firebug, a Firefox plugin.

Firebug has a number of handy tools, the most relevant here probably being the Net panel, which runs loading benchmarks on the various resources required to load the page.

[image]
<sub>(source: [getfirebug.com](http://getfirebug.com/net.gif))</sub>

http://getfirebug.com/

It also comes with a very cool integration with YSlow, Yahoo's page performance/grading tool. It will assign a grade (A-F) to a given page based on a *ton* of criteria, from the number of HTTP requests and javascript file sizes to stuff like "you should use a CDN to deliver content".

Answer (score 2):

I have used [JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/) for this type of benchmarking with good success.

You can script your test suite and then run them whenever you like, against different base URL's.

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of tools to do such things.

First of all, [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) can be a good start, but the best part are the plugins developed by Google and Yahoo :

- [Yahoo YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/)
- [Google PageSpeed](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/)

There is also this tool : http://www.websiteoptimization.com/services/analyze/ which can give you a nice report too.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use ab (apache bench).

```
# logged in user
ab -c 1 -n 100 -C SESSIONID=SESSIONVAL http://example.com/doFoo.php
""" SESSIONID=SESSIONVAL would be an your authentication tokens """

# not logged in user
ab -c 1 -n 100 http://example.com/doFoo.php
```

For the different times of day you'll have to run the tests at different times.

Answer (score 0):

For that kind of "complex" tasks, which implies working with identification, cookies, and all that, I've seen those tools being used :

- [OpenSTA](http://www.opensta.org/)
- [JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/)

If a simpler case (just fetching one page), [ab](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html) is pretty nice -- but for a complex scenario, like going from one page to another, it doesn't do the job : it is only able to fetch one page.

A possibility a bit more evolved than ab, but less complex than OpenSTA, is [Siege](http://freshmeat.net/projects/siege/) : nice thing is it can fetch static files linked from the page you are testing -- after all, JS, CSS, and images also have an impact on the loading time, as perceived by the user !